# UF4-ZrF4 phase diagram

Tags: phase-diagram

I am doing physical chemistry tasks in Professor Peter Atkins book. The phase diagram of UF<sub>4</sub>-ZrF<sub>4</sub> system that I found is in the following picture

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

1. Where is the point that the composition *x*(ZrF<sub>4</sub>) in liquid is equal to 0.40  (at 900<sup>o</sup>C)?

**Thought:** If the point was at the intersect of the *x*
(ZrF<sub>4</sub>) = 0,4 line with 900<sup>o</sup>C line. Then I think that the solution is merely liquid (no solid presents). However, it contradicts with the statement "At 900<sup>o</sup>C, the liquid solution ... is in equilibrium with a solid solution ..." which indicates that there is solid state of ZrF<sub>4</sub>

2. When we are observing the solution below the (L+S) area (*x*(ZrF<sub>4</sub>) = 0.40) but above the tie line passing through eutectic point, is it just UF<sub>4</sub> crystallizes or both ZrF<sub>4</sub> and UF<sub>4</sub> crystallizes at the same time?
3. At 850°C, when the fraction of ZrF4 (x-axis) is equal 0,3 and 0,4. The composition of liquid phase and solid phase remains the same when drawing the tie line. How could this be explained?

Comment: It is not a "series" of solid solutions, it is _a_ solid solution (sigh). And the 900C vs 850C points given are in very different parts of the phase diagram, leading to serious confusion , making the 850C discussion irrelevant to the question (sigh). What a terrible question (and I say that lovingly as a phase diagram nerd).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ad thought:

It is not in contradiction. Notice very different compositions of both phases (0.28, 0.14), compared to $x_\ce{ZrF4} =  0.4$ at $\pu{900 ^{\circ}C}$. The latter will be all liquid until cooled down to $\approx \pu{865 ^{\circ}C}$,  when the solid starts forming with $x_\ce{ZrF4} \approx 0.22$. With progressing cooling, the liquid phase gets progressively enriched by $\ce{ZrF4}$, as the solid is enriched by $\ce{UF4}$.

Ad Q2:

Notice the note *continuous series of solid solutions*.

In a way, the diagram is equivalent to a phase diagram x-T of two miscible liquids with azeotrope with the minimum boiling point. So the solid is the solid solution containing both.

If the liquid mixture $x_\ce{ZrF4} =  0.4$ at $\pu{900 ^{\circ}C}$ is being cooled down, then:

- At $\approx \pu{865 ^{\circ}C}$, the solid solution containing both fluorides starts forming with $x_\ce{ZrF4} \approx 0.22$.
- This is enriching the solid phase by $\ce{UF4}$ while the liquid phase  gets enriched by $\ce{ZrF4}$.
- When the system is further being cooled, the composition of the liquid phase and the momentarily solidified phase follows the isotherm of the current system temperature.
- For the given temperature, these both compositions gradually increase, as lower isotherms cross both composition lines at higher and higher fraction for $\ce{ZrF4}$.
- The system converges to its eutectic, where composition of both phases is equal, with $x_\ce{ZrF4} \approx 0.77$ and the melting point $\approx \pu{765 ^{\circ}C}$.
- At this composition and temperature, the last remnants of the liquid phase finally solidifies.

---

Q3: Composition of both solid and liquid phases remain the same, comparing both states, but the ratio of both phases differ. The state with the overall higher fraction of $\ce{ZrF4}$ will have higher ratio of liquid:solid phase.

Comment: Just to clarify the phrase "solid solution". Should it mean 2 or more solids in a mixture? Or just miscible solids like alloy?

Comment: You do know what solid means and what solution means. then you know what solid solution means = a homogenous solid phase containing 2 or more components. Note that not all alloys are homogenous, having domains of microscopic sizes of different components.

Comment: Furthermore, when we cool down more from 865°C, the tie line indicates more enriched ZrF4 solid and ZrF4 liquid at the same time as the %ZrF4 increases to the right of the diagram. Am I making mistakes here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150624/discussion-between-poutnik-and-shira).