# Enrichment in phase diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-diagram

After my post at [UF<sub>4</sub>-ZrF<sub>4</sub> phase diagram](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/179712/uf4-zrf4-phase-diagram) (the phase diagram is given below)

[image]

**Question:** Consider the coordination (40%; 900<sup>o</sup>C), the cooling to 850<sup>o</sup>C would form *x*(ZrF<sub>4</sub>) = 0,22. When the cooling progresses further, both liquid solution and solid solution are enriched by ZrF<sub>4</sub> (Comparing the solution at point A and B). Is it true in this case?

**Thought:** I was thinking that at liquid solution of composition ZrF<sub>4</sub> = 0,4 which is enriched in UF<sub>4</sub>, The cooling should result in higher UF<sub>4</sub> solid and ZrF<sub>4</sub> liquid. The diagram indicates otherwise.

Comment: The initial solid is higher in UF4, being to the left on the solidus line.

Comment: @JonCuster just to be clear, I added the blue line which represents my first liquid solution being cooled down, the cooling progresses with the enrichment in ZrF4 at both liquid solution and solid solution. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I have had the answer to my problem. To be more specific, when we start from the solidus line, the liquid composition is mainly UF<sub>4</sub>. If the temperature is increased a bit more, both ZrF<sub>4</sub> and UF<sub>4</sub> melts to liquid form. The composition of both solution should change.

It is a bit tricky to understand the solid-liquid phase diagram that is browsed in my question. So let just take liquid-vapor phase diagram of methanol (MeOH) and ethanol (EtOH) as another example.

[image: liquid-vapor phase diagram of methanol and ethanol]

This answer merely points out the composition changes in the LS region.

I guess "phase diagram nerd" like me should wonder about the extent of the vaporization which could be rephrased "As the methanol is the more volatile component, its composition in the gas phase should be enriched and the opposite trend should be seen in the vapor phase." It turns out to be a total mistake.

To put it simply, let's take the example of the starting solution composing of $\pu{60 g}$ MeOH and $\pu{40 g}$ EtOH. At the bubble point line, suppose we have $\pu{10 g}$ of MeOH vaporizes (nearly 100% in the vapor phase). A slight increase in temperature would result to the vaporization of both MeOH and EtOH.

Let's consider the vapor phase first, after the increasing in temperature, suppose MeOH vaporizes additional $\pu{10 g}$, EtOH vaporizes $\pu{5 g}$ simultaneously. Then the composition in the vapor phase now is MeOH ($\pu{20 g}$ or 80%) and EtOH ($\pu{5 g}$ or 20%). So we see the decrease in composition fraction of MeOH (even though MeOH is the more volatile component)

Next, let's consider the liquid phase, after the increasing in temperature, MeOH composition is $60 - 20 = \pu{40 g}$ and EtOH composition is $40 - 5 = \pu{35 g}$. Calculating the fraction, we should see that for MeOH is 53,33% and 46,67% for EtOH.

Comparing two results, the MeOH composition decreases in two phases and it is opposite for EtOH composition. I hope this explanation is useful to other people.

Comment: *At the bubble point line, suppose we have 10g of MeOH vaporizes (100% fraction in the vapor phase).* - This is not true, as the gaseous phase always contains both, if both are present in liquid.

Comment: If $p_\text{M0}$, $p_\text{E0}$ are vapor tension of methanol/ethanol at given $T$, and if $x_\text{l}$ and $x_\text{g}$ are molar fractions of methanol in liquid and gas, then $p_\text{M}=p_\text{M0} . x_\text{l}$, $p_\text{E}=p_\text{E0} .( 1 - x_\text{l})$ and $x_\text{g} = p_\text{M} / ( p_\text{M} + p_\text{E} ) = p_\text{M0} . x_\text{l} / ( p_\text{M0} . x_\text{l} + p_\text{E0} .( 1 - x_\text{l}) )$. All with assumption with zero deviation from Raoult's law.

Comment: I edited. The phrase was to show how the simultaneous and proportional change, so it was a bit unclear.

Comment: Try  `$\ce{UF4}$`  // Chem+Math formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: In phase diagram, both $x,y$ denoted as MeOH. Please correct which one is $x$ and which one is belong to EtOH.

Answer (score 3):

Putting points A and B between the solid and liquid curves is misleading and may confuse for you what is happening. As for the given scenario, the total composition of the whole system is rather a formal parameter after the solidifying starts.

The solid, enriched by $\ce{UF4}$, solidified earlier at higher temperature, is effectively taken away from the equilibrium system and does not take part in further phase exchange.

Therefore, the effective total composition of the system in equilibrium is not constant, but is converging toward the composition of eutectic point.

The liquid phase is enriched by $\ce{ZrF4}$, compared to the new "total composition", which is itself enriched by $\ce{ZrF4}$, compared to initial composition.

The newly being formed solid phase is enriched by $\ce{UF4}$, compared to the new "total composition".

Therefore, in total numbers of fraction composition, both the liquid phase and the newly being formed solid phase are being progressively enriched by $\ce{ZrF4}$. As the newly being formed solid phase is always relatively enriched by $\ce{UF4}$, compared to current liquid phase.

By other words, the total composition of the "equilibrium part of the system", being progressively solidified while cooling, does not reach the inside area between curves. It rather crawls along the upper liquid curve of the diagram toward the eutectic point.
Similarly, the composition of being formed solid phase is crawling along the lower "solid" curve toward the meeting point at the eutectic point.